# Lucas's interesting cipher

Tags: cipher, letters, sequence, letter-sequence

Lucas was fooling around with some letters when he encoded some text into `Gsobj lwmtkd sbceugb vfy rgdjb.`. Can you figure out the original text he had?

> He used a variation of a caesar cipher.

> Hmm... The name Lucas sounds familiar. I think it's a sequence?

> The increment of the caeser cipher is different for each letter.

Comment: Is the  rot13(glcb sbe pnrfne, pnrfre) on purpose?

Comment: @Beothorn, No, I just misspelled it.

Comment: I've been working on this for a bit and rot13(V pna'g frr ubj gur Yhpnf frdhrapr qbrf nalguvat gb gur grkg. V'ir yvgrenyyl gevrq nyy 676 frgf bs 2 fgnegvat ahzoref. V'z nffhzvat vg vf n Ivtrarer pvcure.) Can we get another hint?